# aws-secretsmanager-caching-python :: Is cache shared among different docker containers running on the same EC2 instance?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, caching, aws-secrets-manager

I bumped to this interesting feature of AWS Secret caching:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/use-client-side-caching.html#use-client-side-caching-components

https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-caching-python

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/improve-availability-and-latency-of-applications-by-using-aws-secret-managers-python-client-side-caching-library/

I have a question though:

I am running several different docker containers on the same AWS EC2 instance retrieving AWS Secrets. After implementing **aws-secretsmanager-caching-python** will containers share the same cache or each container will have it's own cache?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

containers are independent of the eachother unless there is some common space share among them to be used as cache.